# How to get supported visual states of a control in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

In `ControlTemplate` I've defined various visual states to change the appearance of a control for a certain state. For ListBox I don't know which visual states to use.

Is there a way to get supported visual states of a control in UWP?

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="?">
                <VisualState x:Name="?" />
                <VisualState x:Name="?" />
                <VisualState x:Name="?" />
                <VisualState x:Name="?" />
                <VisualState x:Name="?" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                FontStyle="Italic"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to find all supported visual states as well as styles and templates is to search directly within the OS-defined resources. On your device go to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\{version}\
```

In this folder you should find `generic.xaml` which contains styles and templates for all controls. Within those styles, you can check the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` to find out everything you need :-) . Make sure not to make any changes to the file itself.

**Note:** In the future (after the release of WinUI 3.0) all styles will be available as part of the [WinUI GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/).

Comment: "In the future (after the release of WinUI 3.0) all styles will be available as part of the WinUI GitHub repo." Not holding my breath.

Comment: @PeterMoore true, the open-sourcing of WinUI was severly delayed and no timeframe in sight